# Karate 0.9.1 is throwing exceptions for soap webservice testing

Tags: karate

I'm trying to test soap webservices using Karate 0.9.1, I created the scenario as per the documentation.

But yet i get exception when i test the soap webservices when passing the webservice request in the test scenario.

**Scenario : 1**
I passed the request as below,

```
* def req=
""" 
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <ns2:QueryUsageBalance xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/usage/V1">
      <ns2:UsageBalance>
          <ns2:LicenseId>12341234</ns2:LicenseId>
      </ns2:UsageBalance>
  </ns2:QueryUsageBalance>
  </S:Body>
  </S:Envelope>
  """
```

**Result**

```
“[Fatal Error] :32:18: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity”
```

**Scenario : 2**

```
Given request
""" 
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <ns2:QueryUsageBalance xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/usage/V1">
      <ns2:UsageBalance>
          <ns2:LicenseId>12341234</ns2:LicenseId>
      </ns2:UsageBalance>
  </ns2:QueryUsageBalance>
  </S:Body>
  </S:Envelope>
  """
```

**Result**

```
“[Fatal Error] :32:18: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity”
```

**Scenario : 3**

```
Given request =
""" 
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
  <ns2:QueryUsageBalance xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/usage/V1">
      <ns2:UsageBalance>
          <ns2:LicenseId>12341234</ns2:LicenseId>
      </ns2:UsageBalance>
  </ns2:QueryUsageBalance>
  </S:Body>
  </S:Envelope>
  """
```

**Result**

```
Program execution freezes and no output
```

Can anyone help me understand what i'm doing wrong here.

I used the same xml in Karate 0.6.1 and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have the triple-quotes on a separate line and you should be fine:

```
* def req =
"""
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:QueryUsageBalance xmlns:ns2="http://www.mycompany.com/usage/V1">    <ns2:UsageBalance>
<ns2:LicenseId>12341234</ns2:LicenseId>
</ns2:UsageBalance>
</ns2:QueryUsageBalance>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
"""
* print req
```

We had asked users to test the beta releases but looks like you haven't seen them: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1064375506202755073

Anyway, if you still see issues like "freezes" please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I edited the request, i'm acutally using the triple-quotes on a seperate line. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: @vasantharajan see the last line above

Comment: My bad, there was some space in there. It's working as expected. Thanks for your inputs.